# Power Apps error ""Office365Groups.ListGroups Failed Authorization_RequestDenied""

Tags: azure-active-directory, office365, powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have this code inside the OnSelect property of a button inside Power Apps canvas application, to get the members of a security group:-

```
Set(
    wAdminID1_1,
    LookUp(
        Office365Groups.ListGroups({'$filter': "startswith(displayName," & "'PPM'" & ")"}).value,
        displayName = varITMGGroupName
    ).id
);
```

now this is working well for me as i am the admin, but for an external user , the user is getting this error:-

[image: johnjohnPter_0-1706399586256.png]

so not sure is this error related to that the user is external or that the user is not admin?

the group is a security group without email, as follow:-

[image: sg.PNG]

any advice?

Comment: Check what access is enabled for guest users in your tenant by referring [this](https://i.imgur.com/GOzsF0W.png). Try assigning Admin role to the guest user and run the code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error **"Insufficient privileges"** usually occurs if the user does not have required permissions or roles to perform the operation.

Usually, external users have **limited** access to directory objects and will get same error from Portal too:

[image]

In your case, check below **settings** to know what access guest users currently have:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, they should be assigned with proper administrator role like this:

[image]

After assigning the role, external user can access the group without any error:

[image]

Similarly, I used below code in **`OnSelect`** property of buttons inside Power Apps canvas application after assigning role and got **response** like this:

**Get Group ID:**

```
Set(
    wAdminID1_1,
    LookUp(
        Office365Groups.ListGroups({'$filter': "startswith(displayName,'PPM-Accounting Team')"}).value,
        true 
    ).id
);
```

**List Group members:**

```
ClearCollect(MembersfromSG,Office365Groups.ListGroupMembers(wAdminID1_1).value)
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: i did not understand your reply,, i do not want to assign the external user admin role to the group...

Comment: Your external user should have valid permissions to list groups and it's members. If you feel admin role is too much, you can create custom directory role with specific permissions and assign it to external user